What is a Nero’s ear cookie?
In “On Food and Cooking” H. McGee refers to a cookie named “Nero’s ear”. What shape and type of a cookie is that?

I don't know, though I will check the Silver Spoon to see if it has a recipe later. I wonder if this is a translation error over time (not in the book) and it is actually called something else in Italian, perhaps something like Oricchio Nero (black ear) and is common in the Italian influenced parts of North America, like New York and Chicago. There's "Nero Cookie" recipes out there, most look like soft chocolate cookie recipes, so perhaps that is what is meant.

No recipes in the Silver Spoon.

Bruce Healy's "The French Cookie Book" has a recipe for sugar cookie called Oreilles de Neron, or Nero's Ears. They are meant to be ear shaped, like a palmier. We can assume that since Emperor Nero was known in part for his ears, that is how they were named.

"Emperor Nero was known in part for his ears" -- is this true? I can't find any other references to Nero's ears related to cooking or otherwise.
